# Error: Cannot find module "@ionic/angular"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i'm trying to implement ion2-calendar from 
https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ion2-calendar

but when i trying to imported to my app.module.ts

i get this error :

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "@ionic/angular"
at webpackMissingModule (calendar.modal.js:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (calendar.modal.js:13)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ff18038c92faa82fd673:54)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:7)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ff18038c92faa82fd673:54)
at Object.355 (main.ts:5)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ff18038c92faa82fd673:54)
at Object.332 (main.ts:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ff18038c92faa82fd673:54)
at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap ff18038c92faa82fd673:25)
```

my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CalendarModule } from 'ion2-calendar';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
HomePage
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,HttpModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
CalendarModule
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
MyApp,
HomePage
],
providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

don't know what's wrong

Comment: according the error, please check that @ionic-angular folder presented or not in node modules

Comment: thank you for your reply,  no i don't see it what should i do

Comment: delete node modules and re install and check ]

Comment: i get the same error

Comment: show us ur node modules structure pointing ionic and ionic-angular folders

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've downloaded the ionic 4 version of the library. Try using https://github.com/HsuanXyz/ion2-calendar/tree/v2 this version is set up for `ionic-angular` not `@ionic/angular` which it looks like your verson is. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you, i had to download the version 2.2.0, now it work, https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion2-calendar